# Using interfaces as class members

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, bean-validation

a simple basic java question here:

in our company code we develop a spring application and heavily use injection in our beans.

Several times in our beans we define interfaces **as class members** like in this excerpt from our application context:

```
<bean id="testDAO" class="it.dao.commerciale.TestDAO">
        <property name="sessionManager" ref="sessionManager" />
        <property name="iDAO" ref="testDAO" />
        <property name="iService" ref="testService" />
</bean>
```

Then we have the corresponding members in our classes difined as private, togheter with getter and setter methods:

```
public class TestDAO implements ITestDAO {
    private IService iService;
    private IDAO iDAO;

    public IDAO getiDAO() {
        return iDAO;
    }

    public void setiDAO(IDAO iDAO) {
        this.iDAO = iDAO;
    }
}
```

It's something we are used to do, but now I'm starting to investigate why we do it.

**What can be the utility in defining an interface as a private member of a class?**

Moreover using the prefix "I" naming convention for interfaces seems to break Spring bean validation rules, since it complains about the absence of a setter that is obviously in place.
If I remove the "I" prefix the error disappears.

**EDIT after reading comment:**

So for example if I have an Engine (as an Interface) I could put inside a class TruckEngine (that implements Engine) an Interface member "Radiator", that does not rely in a particular implementation of the radiator duties.

***What about the validation prefix problem?***

EDIT 2:

After reading dunni comment I found that the validation error was caused by the automatic getter/setter generation in Eclipse. 
In short if the property is named iPropertyName (with a 1-letter lowerscore prefix) the get and set methods will create a "getiPropertyName" with lowercase prefix, and this breaks the validation. I verified this on STS 3.8.1.

Thanks

Comment: It is a very common thing to do when you need *an* implementation of the interface, not *a particular* implementation. e.g. you don't care if it's an `ArrayList` or a `LinkedList`, you just need a `List`.

Comment: Thanks @AndyTurner, I already read the question pointed as duplicate. So for example if I have an Engine (as an Interface) I could put inside a class TruckEngine (that implements Engine) an Interface member "Radiator", that does not rely in a particular implementation of the radiator duties.

What about the validation prefix problem?

Thanks

Comment: If you use proper casing for the method names, it should work, i.e. the convention is (get|set) + uppercase first letter of the field name + rest of the field name. In your case it would be setIDAO or getIDAO.

Comment: Why do you have setters? Won't Spring do constructor injection, or injection directly to the private fields? Setters are arguably an antipattern.

Comment: Thanks both @dunni

Comment: Thanks @DavidConrad.
For the validation problem you're perfecly right, it was caused by the mispelled "I" in the setter/getter methods. I found that it was the automatic get/set creation in eclipse that caused the error.